# Session state variable not setting for all users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session-variables, razor-pages

I have the following code:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string PaRes)
    {
        GenerateAbsoluteURLs();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PaRes))
        {
            throw new Exception($"BAR OnPost() PaRes param string missing from initial response");
        }

        try
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("PaRes", PaRes);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception($"BAR OnPost() Could not set session variables");
        }

        string _PaRes;

        try
        {
            _PaRes = HttpContext.Session.GetString("PaRes");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception($"BAR OnPost() Could not get session variables");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_PaRes))
        {
            throw new Exception($"BAR OnPost() PaRes retrieved null");
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask;

        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostCompleteProcessResponse(string result)
    {
        string _PaRes;

        try
        {
            _PaRes = HttpContext.Session.GetString("PaRes");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception($"BAR OnPCPR() Could not get session variables");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_PaRes))
        {
            throw new Exception($"BAR OnPCPR() PaRes retrieved null");
        }

    }
```

The page is initially called via the OnPost() request.

OnPostCompleteProcessResponse() gets call via ajax on page load.

During debugging, OnPostCompleteProcessResponse() completes after the OnPost().

The code above throws exception: "BAR OnPCPR() PaRes retrieved null" for an increasing number of users in the last week or so.  They seem to be all using Chrome, but have no idea whether this has anything to do with it.

Within Startup.cs, I have set:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

I can't understand how the above can happen.  I have considered cookies being disabled, but it is now affecting nearly 50% of users in the last week, and this seems to high surely to put it down to this, just out of the blue?

Can anybody help point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

EDIT:
This is now happening to me and others internally, and only on Chrome.  I would say it is nearly 100% now.  A few of us were immune last week, even on Chrome, but this week, we are also affected.  Even in debug mode, OnPost() runs first, and the session variables are retrievable.  A second later, when OnPostCompleteProcessResponse() is called, the session variable is cleared.  Debug/Use any other browser, not an issue!  What could be different with Chrome?

EDIT:
Adding the following to Startup.cs looks to fix Chrome (so far, more testing required):

```
   services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

Using this approach, do I need to worry about older browser support, e.g. browser detection?  If so, how do I modify this code, to handle?  Don't forget I am not directly setting cookies, I am setting session variables in the page code itself.

Comment: Is it possible users can call OnGetCompleteProcessResponse() before OnPost()?Or session expired？

Comment: As soon as OnPost() completes, the page is served and loaded, and the client side ajax kicks in and calls OnGetCompleteProcessResponse() immediately - no time to expire happens in seconds.  Without intention (very unlikely given situation), there is no way for OnGetCompleteProcessResponse() to be called before OnPost(), and the frequency this is happening all of a sudden, doesn't fit.

Comment: Is it possible to load the page via HTTP (w/o TLS)? Users could request the page with method=GET and could get a cached version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems this was the issue, and everything has been running fine for a while, so just needed the correct cookie policies within Startup.cs:

```
   services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```